# Reuse ControlTemplate in DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF 4.0 to develop windows and want to reuse a ControlTemplate in my Resources for various Label controls.

I define a generic base Label Style with the ControlTemplate and then define derived Label Styles to control colors and label text.

I then apply these styles to data triggers based on a property value.

What I have tried so far throws an IllegalArgument exception: 'Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies'.

Is there a valid way to do this?

This is what I have so far that produces the exception:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                           />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="AvailableLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseLabelStyle}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="#FF567E4A"/>
            <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Available"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I want to expand the derived styles to define other color and label text changes.

This derived Style is applied here:

```
<Label x:Name="Avail_Out_LBL" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,44,0,0"
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Height="18" 
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
       Grid.Column="1" Padding="0">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MonitorAndControlData.Availability}" Value="Available">
                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource AvailableLabelStyle}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

The exception points to the closing /DataTrigger in the Label.  I can't tell if the problem is in the Style's use or in the definition up top in the Resources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to change the style from the style, which is not permitted.

What I would do in your situation is create a custom UserControl for your label, which would look like this :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                       Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Availability, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type theTypeOfYourControl}}}" Value="Available">
                                <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="#FF567E4A"/>
                                <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Available"/>             
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Label x:Name="Avail_Out_LBL" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,44,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Height="18" 
           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
           Grid.Column="1" Padding="0"/>
</UserControl>
```

The setters in the trigger are probably not good, you'll have to target the right property to make it work. Also, you will need to make a dependency property named Availability or any other relevant name (I just used the name in your binding) to expose it outside the UserControl. You will need to bind to this DependencyProperty when using your UserControl.

Here are some links on how to do it, with more détails :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html